# How to cache the data to use it everytime the app launches in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have a search functionality in my windows phone application where user enter words and the results are returned accordingly. How to cache this search data to use it every time the app launches in windows phone?Whenever this search page is loaded I want to load the search textbox with all the search words used as a context menu.

And also I want to have a checkbox in my application settings which user can use to set application  level settings. And i want to remember these settings every time the app is launched.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Isolated Storage to save data:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you could use local database storage: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-mapping-and-database-operations

it is a little more work and more complex than just sticking data into isolated storage, but it might be a better fit if your data is relational at all, you want to store multiple search queries/results, etc.